# Saving session data before session timeout?

Tags: jakarta-ee, session-timeout

Basically what I'd like to do is to instruct my application to write the session data to a MySQL database before timing out and deleting it from memory.

For example, say I have a User bean that contains the user's name, and I'll be changing that name a lot so storing it to the database every time a change occurs isn't an option, I want to be able to make the changes on RAM. The, when time comes and the user goes inactive, just before unloading it all I want to save it to my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a listener, [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) to be specific. it will give you a callback method called `sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent hse)`, which you can use to implement your session data saving logic.